# How to add buttons in column with equal and dynamic width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add buttons below each other. I want all these buttons to be equal width to the widest button. The button widths vary based on button text and should not be 100%.

```html
<div>
    <div><button type="button">short</button></div>
    <div><button type="button">medium</button></div>
    <div><button type="button">very long</button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Width:100%` will work providing the overall parent shrinks to the width of the largest child

```css
.parent {
  width: max-content;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div><button type="button">short</button></div>
  <div><button type="button">medium</button></div>
  <div><button type="button">very long</button></div>
</div>
```

Or use `inline-block` (or even an `inline-flex` column).

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div><button type="button">short</button></div>
  <div><button type="button">medium</button></div>
  <div><button type="button">very long</button></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Set a permeant width and height to the button by coding class or id

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>

.block 
{
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  border:none;
  background-color: black;
  color: gray;
  padding: 14px 14px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}


.block:hover 
{
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>


<button class="block">Short</button><br>
<button class="block">Medium</button><br>
<button class="block">Very Long</button>

</body>
</html>
```